# How can I attach documentation to members of a python enum?

Tags: python, enums

I'd like to give documentation for each member of a python enum in a way that IPython can find it. What I have right now is something like:

```
class Color(Enum):
    """
    RED: The color red
    GREEN: The color green
    BLUE: The color blue. These docstrings are more useful in the real example
    """
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

This isn't great, as it duplicates the member names, and makes it harder to ask for the documentation for just one member.

I can get what I'm after with

```
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
Color.RED.__doc__ = "The color red"
Color.GREEN.__doc__ = "The color green"
Color.BLUE.__doc__ = "The color blue. These docstrings are more useful in the real example"
```

But this still suffers from repetition of the names.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can override `Enum.__new__` to take a `doc` argument as follows:

```
class DocEnum(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, value, doc=None):
        self = object.__new__(cls)  # calling super().__new__(value) here would fail
        self._value_ = value
        if doc is not None:
            self.__doc__ = doc
        return self
```

Which can be used as:

```
class Color(DocEnum):
    """ Some colors """
    RED   = 1, "The color red"
    GREEN = 2, "The color green"
    BLUE  = 3, "The color blue. These docstrings are more useful in the real example"
```

Which in IPython, gives the following:

```
In [17]: Color.RED?
Type:            Color
String form:     Color.RED
Docstring:       The color red
Class docstring: Some colors
```

---

This can also be made to work for `IntEnum`:

```
class DocIntEnum(IntEnum):
    def __new__(cls, value, doc=None):
        self = int.__new__(cls, value)  # calling super().__new__(value) here would fail
        self._value_ = value
        if doc is not None:
            self.__doc__ = doc
        return self
```

Comment: could it be more flexible with `def __new__(cls, value, doc=''):` ?

Comment: You can do the same thing with `__init__` instead of `__new__`. Or if you want to stick with `__new__`, at least implement it properly with `super().__new__(cls)` rather than `object.__new__(cls)`. Also, you forgot to make `Color` inherit from `DocEnum`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Calling `super().__new__(cls)` doesn't work, as that calls `Enum.__new__` which isn't ready to be called yet. Overriding `__init__` also doesn't work, because then it's too late and now `Color.RED.value` is a tuple, not the intended integer.

Comment: Curious. I don't know why `super().__new__(cls, value)` doesn't work, but [using `__init__` definitely does](https://repl.it/repls/UnwieldySelfassuredClimate).

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Ok, `__init__` does work, but not for `IntEnum`

Comment: It looks like `Enum` is just really weird, in that `Enum.__new__` does not support being used for initial construction of enum instances at all; it *only* handles retrieving already-constructed instances once the class is already set up. During enum class initialization, `Enum.__new__` is explicitly bypassed for instance creation.

Comment: Source references [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/enum.py#L515), [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/enum.py#L124), and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Lib/enum.py#L462).

Comment: Mistaken downvote. Sorry. I don't understand the rationale for not letting one change a mistaken vote.

Comment: @ChristopherBarber: edited question so you can remove your down-vote.  There is very short time window in which to remove a vote (15 seconds?  10?)

Answer (score 6):

@Eric has shown [how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473952/208880) using the stdlib `Enum`; this is how to do it using [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/)<sup>1</sup>:

```
from aenum import Enum  # or IntEnum


class Color(Enum):                     # or IntEnum

    _init_ = 'value __doc__'

    RED = 1, 'The color red'
    GREEN = 2, 'The color green'
    BLUE = 3, 'The color blue'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: I was hoping that your package might support this, but I'd forgotten its name, and your docs don't mention using `__doc__` explicitly. Perhaps an example like this in the documentation would be useful?

Comment: Is `value` handled specially here? In the stdlib, I have to use `_value_` in my `__new__`.

Comment: @Eric:  Yes, `value` is handled specially; if it's mentioned in `_init_` then it's peeled off and used during `EnumMeta`'s `__new__`, while the rest are sent to the default `__init__` which assigns to attributes of the same name (sort of like `**kwargs`).

Comment: Could that sort of functionality have a chance of getting integrated into the stdlib enum? This is a great feature.

Comment: @jxramos: Probably not, but as you can see it's easy to add.